# How do I set the session param for multiple namespaces?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If I am handling authentication manually, and am setting session like so:

```
session[:user_id] = authenticated.user.id
```

user_id does not show up in my session hash when viewed from another namespace.  In this instance I have a namespace :api, and session doesn't show up at api/show/current.  How do I set the session hash to be viewed in both namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

The session is completely independent from namespaces, maybe there is something else wrong with your app?

where do you set the user_id?
maybe providing more code helps